# Firebase Cloud Functions - How to use same return value in multiple .then() methods

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a Firebase Cloud Function that does the following, using the Firebase Admin SDK:

1. Creates user with email/password.
2. Creates a Firestore doc, with reference the newly created UID.
3. Returns a Firebase JWT token to the client, if 1 & 2 are successful.

The code I have so far is below:

```js
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin
      .auth()
      .createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        phoneNumber: data.number,
      })
      .then((user) => {
        return admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("collectionName")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set({});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
      });
  });
```

What I'm struggling with is the next `.then()` in the chain, to return the JWT token. I'm aware of the actual Admin SDK code to return a JWT, but I'm not sure how I can access the new user's properties in multiple `.then()`s, while also returning a promise (which I think is necessary for proper function termination?)

How can I add another `.then()` that has access to `user.uid` and also ensures the function instance is not prematurely terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a variable as shown below:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    let userObject;

    return admin
      .auth()
      .createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        phoneNumber: data.number,
      })
      .then((user) => {
        userObject = user
        return admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("collectionName")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set({});
      })
      .then(() => {
        const user = userObject;
        // Do whathever you want with user
        await function(user)
        
        // Don't forget to return data that can be JSON encoded, see the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result
        // In your case the JWT Object I guess
        return ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
        // See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
      });
  });
```

---

If you use `async/await` it is even easier:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const user = await admin
      .auth()
      .createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        phoneNumber: data.number,
      });

    await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("collectionName")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set({}); 

    // Do whathever you want with user
    await function(user)

    return ...

  });
```

Comment: Thanks very much Renaud!

In your second example, do I need to return a promise or can it be any JSON encoded data?

Doc says 'To return data after an asynchronous operation, return a promise', but perhaps the async/await renders this unnecessary. Do you know?

Comment: You can return any JSON encoded data: if you use await with all asynchronous method calls you are sure that at the end all these asynchronous calls have been completed (or have thrown an error). BTW you should use a try/catch block, which I didn't do in my example.